# How to get Unique list of particular column based on condition on another column in LIST<T>

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of class objects. List name is "PERSON" & fields are "Name, BirthMonth, BirthYear". Now I want to select only Unique BirthMonth which is in Particular BirthYear.

Suppose data is as below:

```
Name BirthMonth BirthYear
ABC  1          1990
XYZ  3          1990
PQR  1          1990
TVW  12         1985
```

**I want result like below:**

```
BirthMonth BirthYear
1          1990
3          1990
12         1985
```

I have tried following but it dont work:

```
var ele = Model.ToList();
var item = ele.Distinct(ele.SelectMany(x => x.Mon).Where(x => x.Year_No = prevYear));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = input.Select(x => new { x.BirthMonth, x.BirthYear }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: @Aron You're wrong. Anonymous types **do** implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. Read the last paragraph at [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx): *Because the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on anonymous types are defined in terms of the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods of the properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if all their properties are equal.* That's why you can use all `HashSet`-related LINQ methods, like `Distinct` over collection of anonymous type instances.

Comment: But I now want an one element from new list, where Year = 1990. Then How can I do that?

Comment: I am not able to get that element as like results.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Year_No == "1990");

Comment: @What do you mean by  *one element, where Year=1990*?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I mean now want to select one item from new list.

Comment: Well, you can use indexing property, you can use `First` method, you can do many things. It's just a list. I still don't get where is your problem now.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek okies. When I do debug I found new list fields are named as Item1, Item2. Can I rename it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44838/discussion-between-marcinjuraszek-and-dks)